# Convert date in textboxes to date in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, date

I am working in ASP.NET as front end and SQL Server 2012 as backend. In ASP.NET, the user enters a date in 3 textboxes in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

Now I have concatenated these textbox values into a string. In SQL Server, I want to save this date into column `DOB` with a data type of `DATE`.

Below is concatenated string in ASP.net

```
string strDOB = txtYY.Text + "/" + txtMM.Text + "/" + txtDD.Text;
```

How can I now save this `strDOB` in SQL Server?

Comment: Why not use a date picker on the application, rather than trusting the user will enter a valid date string. If they enter the string `'07/01/2018'`, how do you know whether that is 07 January or 01 June? And no, the answer isn't "because the user will always enter in the format dd/MM/yyyy." Users are fickle and unpredictable creatures and should never/rarely be trusted to be consistent.

Comment: If Damien's answer is preferred, you can mark it as such. The A part of Q&A is the lifeblood of SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using strings. Besides the advice in the comments to use a dedicated picker control, the next best advice is to parse those strings into integers (briefly), then construct a `DateTime` object from that and then *do not let it get converted back into a string*. It's when people let extra string/date conversions happen that they *introduce* formatting problems. So get the value:

```
var year = Int32.Parse(txtYY.Text);
var month = Int32.Parse(txtMM.Text);
var day = Int32.Parse(txtDD.Text);

var dob = new DateTime(year,month,day);
```

And then pass it to SQL Server:

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(...);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOB",SqlDbType.Date).Value = dob;
```

And make sure that your query uses the parameter `@DOB` wherever you want to use that value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Column] = '' + strDOB + ''
```

Be careful, though... this hasn't been sanitized to guard against SQL Injection. I've only demonstrated the direct answer to your question, nothing more.

As a best practice, you should never concatenate together unchecked user input and store the result in a column. Techniques for preventing this are outside the scope of this Q&A, but are easily discovered with a minimal amount of searching.

**--EDIT--**

I defer to Damien's answer on this one. I agree with his syntax suggestions.

Comment: If you know that doing this is bad practice and vulnerable to SQL Injection (actually it is a no-go) then it should not be added as an answer, should it?

Comment: But this is "Let SQL Server perform a default conversion from string to date and *hope* it's interpretation matches yours". Not ideal.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer ~ Because it's outside the scope of the Q&A.

Comment: *if* you're going to pass a string to SQL Server at all that should in fact be a `date`, you should at least  use an *explicit* `CONVERT` specifying the *style* parameter that you know matches the string you're passing.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer ~ I don't know whether it was you who downvoted, but if it was I appreciate the accompanying comment. As you may have noticed elsewhere, I'm on a campaign against drive-by-downvoters. I don't mind a downvote so much as I mind a SILENT downvote.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ~ Got it, thanks. I don't know exactly how to do that yet, so I'll have to do some research before editing. Also: I don't know whether it was you who downvoted, but if it was I appreciate the accompanying comment. As you may have noticed elsewhere, I'm on a campaign against drive-by-downvoters. I don't mind a downvote so much as I mind a SILENT downvote.

Comment: @InteXX Yes, I downvoted. And I didn't want to question your proficiency in any way. I also agree that it might be out of scope of the Q&A however, Stack Overflow is also a resource for code examples and people come here from google and other places. So I hope the downvote is understood as a statement for "pls dont do this".